# Tabela com PUG no NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pug

Estou usando template PUG no NodeJS e estou procurando na documentação como montar uma tabela. Estou verificando no "pugjs.org", mas aparentemente não existe... Alguém sabe como faz para montar uma tabela com PUG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faça como com outros parâmetros

```
table.table
    thead
        tr
            th Exemplo
            th Exemplo2
    tbody
        tr
            td
            td
        tr
            td
            ....
```

Se quiser fazer com dados dinâmicos, utilize each.

```
table.table(class=type)
    thead
        tr
            each head, i in header
                th #{head}
    tbody
        each row,j in data
            tr
                each col,k in row
                    td #{col}
```

Comment: Gabriel, obrigado pelas informações. O primeiro exemplo funcionou sem problemas, porém preciso do seu segundo exemplo, ou seja, dinamicamente. Um dos problemas que estou tendo é como definir dinamicamente o "colspan" e o "rowspan", por exemplo. Você poderia compartilhar o link da documentação sobre Tabelas no PUG? realmente não estou encontrando no "pugjs.org".